# Google Sheets to Web App

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am wondering what the guidlines are for turning a gsheet into a web app.  I am creating a very complex spreadsheet to eventually be turned into a proprietary business web application, but I want to make sure that I build it to the needed specs for easy development.  I am open to suggestions about the best way to code the final product.  It is very formula and calculation heavy, spanning more than one workbook.

Answer (score -1):

Quite simple to publish as a web app. Just make sure you submit a new version on any changes you make in Google App Script.

Google AppScript-Publish-Deploy as a web app

You could also embed into a HTML page, using the embed section from "Publish to the Web" under the File dropdown menu.